# Dataframe.multiply method generate NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I am trying to multiply a Dataframe element-wise by a series using the dataframe's .multiply method. In this case, converting the open and close dollar prices into Pounds. Somehow it keeps on returning NaN values. Any idea what is the problem? I already checked the datatypes in both objects and verified they are floats.

```
# Subset 'Open' & 'Close' columns from sp500: dollars
dollars = sp500[['Open', 'Close']]

# Convert dollars to pounds: pounds
pounds = dollars[['Open', 'Close']].multiply(exchange['GBP/USD'], axis='rows')

# Print the head of dollars
print(dollars.head())

# Print the head of exchange
print(exchange.head())

# Print the head of pounds
print(pounds.head())
```

Below is the output.

```
                   Open        Close
Date                                
2015-01-02  2058.899902  2058.199951
2015-01-05  2054.439941  2020.579956
2015-01-06  2022.150024  2002.609985
2015-01-07  2005.550049  2025.900024
2015-01-08  2030.609985  2062.139893
            GBP/USD
Date               
2015/01/02  0.65101
2015/01/05  0.65644
2015/01/06  0.65896
2015/01/07  0.66344
2015/01/08  0.66151
            Open  Close
Date                   
2015-01-02   NaN    NaN
2015-01-05   NaN    NaN
2015-01-06   NaN    NaN
2015-01-07   NaN    NaN
2015-01-08   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Please check if the columns are defined as integer and not as object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert first your index to `datetime` type use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```py
exchange.index = pd.to_datetime(exchange.index)
dollars.index = pd.to_datetime(dollars.index)

pounds = dollars[['Open', 'Close']].multiply(exchange['GBP/USD'], axis='rows')
pounds
                   Open        Close
Date
2015-01-02  1340.364425  1339.908750
2015-01-05  1348.616555  1326.389506
2015-01-06  1332.515980  1319.639876
2015-01-07  1330.562125  1344.063112
2015-01-08  1343.268811  1364.126161
```

Comment: Where does the 'axis="rows"' annotation come from?

The documentation shows either 0 or "index"

Comment: Sorry i don't remember it could be in old doc.